# Mathematical objects locally Banach

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was thinking of differential manifolds as those mathematical objects that locally look like $\mathbb R^n$ for some finite $n$. Is it possible for a family to exist that locally resembles $\mathbb R^\infty$? Perhaps the question can be given in a slightly more general way: Is it possible for a family to exist that locally resembles a Banach space with finite or infinite dimension? If the answers are affirmative, could you give me some reference to be able to read a little about the subject?

I took the differential topology course some time ago and I haven't been able to get that question out of my head. I appreciate all kinds of help.

Comment: [Banach manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold)

Comment: For a reference,  Serge Lang's [Book](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4612-0541-8.pdf) works in this setting. (But also see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131053/differentiable-manifolds-by-serge-lang-question#comment337658_131053) and the one after it)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference and the comment, they are very useful!